# Tank tracks seem to be not following the curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

The curve and array are applied properly but it seems it doesn't want to follow the curve but go straight.

When I move the model it all rotates at the same time. I have tried tutorials but nothing works.

[image: Example of issues]

Comment: Order of modifiers is wrong, Array should to be placed before Curve deform

Comment: Thanks. I was baffled.